# C# HttpClient not displaying all cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, session-cookies, .net-core

Edit: I apologize for the confusion: I'm attempting to scrape a site that I did not write; I'm not writing an ASP app. I'm only attempting to scrape one.

After making a post request to a login page, I attempt to read the cookies from another page. I do not see all the cookies I expect, however. My code is as follows:

```
// Downloads login cookies for subsequent requests
public async Task<CookieContainer> loginCookies()
{
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
        UseCookies = true,
        AllowAutoRedirect = true,
        CookieContainer = cookies
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var loginUri = new Uri("https://connect.example.edu/login.aspx");

    var credentials = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"example$txtUsername", this.Username},
        {"example$txtPassword", this.Password}
    };

    var formCredentials = new FormUrlEncodedContent(credentials);
    await client.PostAsync(loginUri, content: formCredentials);

    var pointsUri = new Uri("https://info.example.edu/");

    Console.WriteLine("COOKIES:");
    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies.GetCookies(pointsUri))
        Console.WriteLine($"{cookie.Name} --> {cookie.Value}");

    return cookies;
}
```

I believe the error is a result of `loginUri` and `pointsUri` having different subdomains. The info I need to scrape exists at the `pointsUri` page, but the login exists at `loginUri`.

A cookie that I'm missing in particular is `ASP.NET_SessionID`.

Comment: To share the cookie between subdomains, the server code for those domains should probably be setting the domain property of the cookie (to .example.edu, for example).  If you can get that set or control it anyway.  Reference: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm

Comment: I am attempting to scrape an existing site (that I did not write). I believe the linked site is for managing cookies server side, right?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the request and response of the first url?

Comment: @davenportw15 the link is mostly for the server-side management yes, because well behaved http clients wouldn't share a domain's cookie with another domain (or subdomain).. maybe you can make a more raw tcp request without using httpclient, then you can cache/scrape/reuse whatever you like.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli I'm actually developing this on Mac. (Cross-platform .NET Core!) I don't believe Fiddler runs on Mac... Is there another tool I could use to provide you with the information?

Comment: @davenportw15 https://www.charlesproxy.com

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Installing it now.

Comment: Along the way, I discovered that an intermediate redirect uses js to submit a form as a preventative measure for scraping. The result of posting to that page sets the JSESSIONID, which seems odd to me. Isn't that Tomcat? Is there any specific info you want, @GerardoGrignoli?

Comment: @davenportw15 you should compare your browser trace against your c# one, find the missing cookies and make them happen manually. The JS code is probably setting a cookie so you may need to extract a few things from there. Or you can do a totally different approach and try to 'control' a web browser using Selenium or PhantomJS (with c# wrapper) but neither work on .NET Core.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Yeah, Selenium or Phantom is probably the way to go, unfortunately. Thank you for all the help.